# delete of HttpClient causing error callback when backend returns success response

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient, http-delete

I'm trying to delete a simple student object by It's ID. It works fine. but instead of showing the successful message, It returns the success message as an error message.

**the backend code in java ->**
**the controller code:**

```
@DeleteMapping("/student/{$id}")
    public String deleteStudent(@PathVariable int $id){
        return student_service.deleteStudent($id);
    }
```

**the service code:**

```
public String deleteStudent(int $id){
        student_repository.deleteById($id);
        return "student deleted, id: "+$id;
    }
```

**the forntend code in angular ->**
**the service code:**

```
public deleteStudentById($id: number): Observable<string>{
    return this.http.delete<string>(this.url + `student/${$id}`);
  }
```

**the main class code:**

```
deleteStudentById($id: number): void{
    this.httpService.deleteStudentById($id)
      .subscribe(
        (res => console.log(res)),
        (error => console.log(error))
      );
  }
```

**Error in console:**

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/student/3", ok: false, …}
SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:124662:51) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:495:35) at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:82248:33) at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:494:40) at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:263:51) at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:576:38) at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1717:18) at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1754:25)
message: "Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0"
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0↵    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:124662:51)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:495:35)↵    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:82248:33)↵    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:494:40)↵    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:263:51)↵    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:576:38)↵    at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1717:18)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1754:25)"
__proto__: Error
constructor: ƒ SyntaxError()
message: ""
name: "SyntaxError"
__proto__: Object
text: "student deleted, id: 3"
__proto__: Object
headers: HttpHeaders
lazyInit: () => {…}
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
__proto__: Object
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/student/3"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/student/3"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

[1]

**The text message is exactly what i want to return as successful message.**
But It shows that as an error.

Sorry, I forgot the declaration section. Here the http is type of HttpClient.

```
private http: HttpClient;
private url: string = 'localhost:8080'; 
private httpService: StudentService;
```

Console screenshot here[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW1Ql.png

Comment: Calling your backend with cURL (and not Angular) is working? What does the rest of the frontend service looks like (e. g. how is `http` initialized)? More details, this is not a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: private http: HttpClient;    \n

private url: string = 'http://localhost:8080/';   \n

private httpService: StudentService;    \n

Sorry, I forgot the declaration section. Here the http is type of HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular HTTP Client expects a JSON Object as response content. Your endpoint, however, provides a plain text. Please use the respective response type.

```
return this.http.delete<string>(this.url + `student/${$id}`, { responseType: 'text' });
```

Comment: TS2322: Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'.   Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.
The IDE doesn't allow me to do that!!!